# Clean way to use optionals on optionals - Java?

Tags: java, option-type

I need to get an optional value depending on another optional value. Here's an overly simplified example of what I mean:

```
Optional<SomeA> someA = callSomeFunctionThatReturnsOptionalSomeA(....);
Optional<SomeB> someB = // if someA is present, call some method to get value of someB, if someA is not present, don't bother and just return an empty optional.
```

I know I can do this with else/if for `someA.isPresent()` but I want to try using a shorter way of doing this (using map on the optional?) if possible. Any tips?

Comment: A ternary. Or, Conditional Operator `? :`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Optional someA = callSomeFunctionThatReturnsOptionalSomeA(....); 
Optional someB = someA.map(n -> transformFirstResult(n));
```

It's as simple as this.

`someB` will contain the return value of `transformFirstResult()` if `someA` had a value, and will be empty otherwise. (If `transformFirstResult()` itself returns an optional, you need to use `flatMap()` instead of `map()` to avoid ending up with an optional of an optional.)

It's these methods (`map()`, `orElse()`, `orElseGet()`, `orElseThrow()` and `filter()`) that make `Optional` really useful. If you only use `isPresent()` and `get()`, you haven't really won much (though it makes the contract of a method more explicit, which is a good thing) in practice.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement. Using `Optional`, however you use it, is explicit about your intentions. It's right there in the signature of your method. Using `null` as a sentinel value accomplishes the same thing but implicitly. Besides looking at the implementation or reading the documentation, you would never know whether to expect it or not.

Comment: @Michael That's a very slim advantage though.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. [Null is evil](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)

Comment: @Michael Fair enough, that's your opinion. My opinion for example is that if you've called `ifPresent()` or `get()`, you've already made a mistake. Regardless, my statement stands, it's those methods that make `Optional` useful and elegant, without them it's just a construct to kick a problem a bit further down the road.

Comment: @Michael I generally think `null` is evil in public APIs.  Internally, I don't need an excess of `Optional<T>` wrapper objects adding pressure on my garbage collector. It's going to vary by use case, not an absolute rule.

Comment: @Michael By the way, I don't disagree with you about `null` in general, all I'm saying is that squeezing an `Optional` class into Java (instead of having it as part of the type system, like you do in functional languages) is not a massive win in itself. But make it do things so that you never have to unwrap the value in them, and now we're cooking with gas. (I've rephrased my answer to reflect this, so thanks for your comments.)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
return getA(...).isPresent() ? getB(...) : Optional.empty();
```